# Add references in system so that not to include again?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I want to add `#include "List.h"`
in reference for that purpose i have to add `sys` `machine` `vm` `bsm` and other references files that are 100 in number my code not accepting this

`<sys/kernel.h>`

so i have to manually download and add like that

```
  #include "sys/param.h"   
  #include  <sys/kernel.h> 
  #include "sys/queue.h"   
  #include "sys/cpuset.h"  
  #include "sys/lock.h"    
  #include "sys/mutex.h"   
  #include "sys/proc.h"    
  #include "sys/vnode.h"   
  #include "sys/conf.h"    
  #include "sys/socket.h"  
  #include "sys/mbuf.h"    

  #include "sys/bpf.h"     
  #include "sys/if.h"      
  #include "sys/if_var.h"  
  #include "sys/if_types.h"
  #include "sys/if_media.h"

  #include <netinet/in.h>  
  #include <netinet/in_pcb.

  #include <netinet6/in6_va
  #include <netinet6/nd6.h>

  #include "vm/vm.h"       
  #include <vm/vm_object.h>`
```

this create further problem like i have to add more files the basic file i need is `List.h` header file so can anybody tell me solution from `"sys/kernal.h" to <sys/kernal.h>` and where is **List.h**

Comment: this is list http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/list.h